# Python and Windows 10 Max Path Length

Tags: python, windows

Is there a setting in Python 2.7.4 to enable long file name processing on Windows 10?

In the registry under Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem I see the flag for LongPathsEnabled is set to 1 or true.

I found that I am able to copy a file to a new location from a CMD shell that creates a total path length longer than 260.

But in a python 2.7 script, when a file is attempted to be opened for write with a path too long, the following error is given:

```
error in write
    file = open(path, 'w')
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: "c:\\..."
```

It may be some other problem, but the creation of files with shorter path lengths seem to be working OK.

Comment: Long paths have to be enabled both at the system level and in the application's manifest. It's enabled for Python 3.6+ if you can upgrade. Otherwise you could modify the embedded manifest in "python.exe".

Comment: However if you're writing a script that needs to run in Windows 7 and 8, this new long-path feature shouldn't be used. Use a \\?\ (extended device) path instead. It has to be Unicode, fully-qualified, and only use backslash as the path separator. In this case UNC paths (e.g. `r"\\server\share\file"`) should use the "UNC" device (e.g. `r"\\?\UNC\server\share\file"`).